# $n$-th root of a positive element in an ordered field

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

In Rudin's real analysis, there is a statement that says that for every positive real number $x$ and for each positive integer $n$, there is one and only one real number $y$ such that $y^{n} = x$. My question is kind of similar but with a little variant. It is the following:

Does there exist an ordered field $F$ other than $\mathbb{R}$ such that it satisfy the following two properties:

(1) every positive element of $F$ has an $n$-th root for all positive integers $n$,

(2) for any positive integer $n$, the map $f: F^{+} \rightarrow F$ defined by $f(x) = y$, where $y^{n} = x$, is a continuous function under the order topology.

Comment: Any real closed field satisfies those properties. You get one for every cardinal if I recall correctly.

Comment: Doesn't (2) follow from the definition of an ordered field? Or, what do you mean by "convex"?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it indeed follows from the definition.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Ratanjit - I could have missed your comment. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/when-is-ping-necessary-to-cause-comment-notification-to-take-place